# Bug in Bjornstrup style of fncychap (the second line does not stretch until the end)?

Tags: sectioning, margins, incompatibility, fncychap

I am using the `\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}`. The problem I encountered is shown in figure [image: attachment]. How can I fix it?

I tried changing the style file from:

```
409   \addtolength{\mylen}{-2\myhi}
```

to

```
409   \addtolength{\mylen}{1.7\myhi}
```

and it fixes the problem, but it is ugly and can potentially have side affects.  Is  there a better way?

Using texlive 2012 on mac.

**Update:** I am using a template there I found that some settings in the margins might be causing this. Working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}

\oddsidemargin 5mm
\evensidemargin 5mm
\textwidth 150mm
\topmargin 0mm
\headheight 0mm
\textheight 225mm

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter title}
lorem impsum.

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).  Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).  A simple test of the code you post in the standard book class, does not demonstrate the problem you see.

Comment: @AndrewSwann , thanks for reply. I updated the question with an example. I guess the problem is margin (\textwidth) settings in the template I use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your immediate issue can be solved by changing `\textwidth` & friends *before* loading `fncychap`. However, in LaTeX documents based on the standard classes it is good practice to use the [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package for modifying page margins; in your example I suggest

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[hcentering,textwidth=150mm,textheight=225mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter title}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Just need to put the `\textwidth` before the package declaration.
Fixed example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\textwidth 150mm
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}

\oddsidemargin 5mm
\evensidemargin 5mm
\topmargin 0mm
\headheight 0mm
\textheight 225mm

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter title}
lorem impsum.

\end{document}
```